# `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` for accessing SFTP on a localhost instance

Tags: ssh, sftp

I inherited an unusual configuration for SFTP where a system uses a locally-running SFTP instance to load a directory on an NFS share, that is symlinked in `/var/sftp` as its default, but when connection attempts are made using SFTP libraries, the connection fails.

```
debug1: identity file /home/testuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/testuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/testuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/testuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/testuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/testuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/testuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
testlab1@localhost's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Connection closed.
Connection closed
```

When testing using the SFTP command, it dies with `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` as seen above. My initial research indicates its a perms issue, which I have no control over with a symlink. The subdirectories inside the symlink are set to 0755 and are not owned by the same `root` user that the parent symlink is, but are part of the sftp group that is set with a `Match Group` in sshd_config. Similarly, `ChrootDirectory` in sshd_config is also set to %h.

```
$ ls -aluth
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   36 Dec 13 18:05 directory -> /mnt/nfs1/target-directory
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Dec 13 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4.0K Dec 12 20:05 ..
```

Is the issue as simple as the symlink permissions here, and if so, are there any workarounds that would allow SFTP to connect to the directory in this link?

Comment: Do you find any errors in the sshd logfile?  Problems with the permissions of the path to the landing directory will be reported there.  Is your sftp command attempting to log into a different user's account, or the same user?